# Populating ComboBox in User Control

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I'm trying to understand the life cycle of a UserControl within a Form. The following is a test project, yet, UserControl1 (added via the Designer) is showing but no data populated in ComboBox1. UserControl2 doesn't show (added at Form1 OnLoad event), and UserControl3 doesn't show via a Button event. Any help would be appreciated.

Here's the code for Form1:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ComboBoxTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (UserControl1 ucCtrl = new UserControl1())
            {
                groupBox2.Controls.Add(ucCtrl);
                ucCtrl.BringToFront();
            }
        }

        private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (UserControl1 ucCtrl = new UserControl1())
            {
                groupBox3.Controls.Clear();
                groupBox3.Controls.Add(ucCtrl);
                ucCtrl.BringToFront();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here's the code for UserControl1

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ComboBoxTest
{
    public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
    {
        public UserControl1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            PopulateComboBox();
        }

        private void PopulateComboBox()
        {
            using (DataTable dtData = new DataTable())
            {
                DataColumn dtCol;
                DataRow dtRow;

                dtCol = new DataColumn
                {
                    DataType = typeof(Int32),
                    ColumnName = "Index"
                };
                dtData.Columns.Add(dtCol);

                dtCol = new DataColumn
                {
                    DataType = typeof(String),
                    ColumnName = "Option"
                };
                dtData.Columns.Add(dtCol);

                for (int xI = 0; xI < 5; xI++)
                {
                    dtRow = dtData.NewRow();

                    dtRow["Index"] = xI;
                    dtRow["Option"] = "Option " + Convert.ToString(xI);
                    dtData.Rows.InsertAt(dtRow, xI);
                }
                comboBox1.DataSource = dtData;
                comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Option";
                comboBox1.ValueMember = "Index";
                comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The purpose of a UserControl is generally to encapsulate the functionality for some number of controls and 'hide' it away.  As such, the foirm doesnt usually get involved directly.  Ideally, you would "tell" the usercontrol to do something like GetReady and it would then fiddle with all the components for you

Comment: Remove the using statements...the control is getting disposed in the load and click events.

Comment: On another note, you'll have the same issue with the `PopulateComboBox` routine as well, when the end of the `using` is hit, your `dtData` will be disposed of.

Comment: Omg, my problem was just the 'using' statement, everything worked now. Very grateful Zaggler. How can I mark the correct answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> UserControl1 (added via the Designer) is showing but no data populated in ComboBox1. UserControl2 doesn't show (added at Form1 OnLoad event), and UserControl3 doesn't show via a Button event

The root issue is because you've wrapped the construction in `using` statements. For example:

```
 using (UserControl1 ucCtrl = new UserControl1())
 {
    groupBox2.Controls.Add(ucCtrl);
    ucCtrl.BringToFront();
 }
```

To fix your issue's, just remove the `using` statements as when it hits the end of the `using`, the usercontrol is disposed of.

For example of the above (`using` removed):

```
 UserControl1 ucCtrl = new UserControl1();
 groupBox2.Controls.Add(ucCtrl);
 ucCtrl.BringToFront();
```

Comment: Many thanks Zaggler, I was thinking big like Form or UserControl life cycle. All worked very well now. 